# Convert C-Source image dump from RGB565 into RGB888

Tags: c, image-processing, gimp

I  have created with GIMP a C-Source image dump like the following:

```
/* GIMP RGBA C-Source image dump (example.c) */

static const struct {
  guint      width;
  guint      height;
  guint      bytes_per_pixel; /* 2:RGB16, 3:RGB, 4:RGBA */ 
  guint8     pixel_data[304 * 98 * 2 + 1];
} example= {
  304, 98, 2,
  "\206\061\206\061..... }
```

Is there a way to convert this image from RG565 to RGB888?

I mean , I have found a way to covert pixel by pixel:

```
 for (i = 0; i < w * h; i++)
   {
      uint16_t color = *RGB565p++;
      uint8_t r = ((color >> 11) & 0x1F);
      uint8_t g = ((color >> 5) & 0x3F);
      uint8_t b = (color & 0x1F);

      r = ((((color >> 11) & 0x1F) * 527) + 23) >> 6;
      g = ((((color >> 5) & 0x3F) * 259) + 33) >> 6;
      b = (((color & 0x1F) * 527) + 23) >> 6;

      uint32_t RGB888 = r << 16 | g << 8 | b;
      printf("%d \n", RGB888);
   }
```

the problem is that using this logic I get numbers that are not represented as the one used n the original image:

```
P3
304 98
255
3223857
3223857
3223857
3223857
3223857
3223857
3223857
3223857
```

Did I miss something?

EDIT: here you can find the original image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YBphg5_V6M2FA3HWcaFZT4fHqD6yeEOl/view

Comment: How about this? for (i = 0; i < w * h; i++)
   {
      uint16_t color = *RGB565p++;
      uint8_t r = ((color >> 11) & 0x1F);
      uint8_t g = ((color >> 5) & 0x3F);
      uint8_t b = (color & 0x1F);

      uint32_t RGB888 = r << 16 | g << 8 | b;
      printf("%d \n", RGB888);
   }

Comment: Why do you apply this weird linear transformation after unpacking ??

Comment: `RG565` for example only uses 5 bits for the red channel.  When this is increased to 8 bits the value need to be scaled to make use of the additional range.  So the value for each channel changes but still uses the same relative value for each channel range,

Comment: @D023F sorry what's the difference with the one provided by me in the example?

Comment: @YvesDaoust you mean the first three lines of code in the loop? yes they could have contained already the transformation in the second 3 lines...

Comment: No, this is not what I mean.

Comment: Where did you get those formulas from ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust can you please provide an example? keep in mind I need the same representation of the original image but using the RGB888 decoding

Comment: @YvesDaoust from Internet , what I have understood so far is that the first 3 lines extract the 5 , 6 and 5 bits that contain the red green and blue bits and then the next 3 lines convert r5 into r8 g6 into g8 and b5 into b8

Comment: Where from Internet ?

Comment: @RichardCritten I didn't get your comment, can you please provide an example?

Comment: @YvesDaoust https://forum.arduino.cc/t/help-converting-rgb565-to-rgb888/275681

Comment: I can't interpret this post-transformation.

Comment: _"...I get numbers that are not represented as the one used n the original image..."_ the numbers have been scaled after extraction because of the additional range.  The red channel only uses 5 bits so `11111` is max red. When increased to 8 bits `11111` is not max red `11111111` is max red, so all the values have to have a scaling factor applied.

Comment: @RichardCritten yes I know that, I'm saying they should have the same format as in the original image, I have updated my question with a link to the complete code representation of the image

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm a totally newbie (in image conversion/representation) so if you think that post-transformation is wrong most probably you are right, can you please provide the correct one?

Comment: Can you include an example of what you are getting and what you expect to get and how it's different?

Comment: No, as long as I don't understand what it is doing there. Maybe it is required in your case.

Comment: @PaulHankin I have edited the question in any case I would like to have the same representation of this: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YBphg5_V6M2FA3HWcaFZT4fHqD6yeEOl/view

because I have already the code in C++ to draw this type of images (created with GIMP) on the screen.

I need to have the same thing but instead of RGB565 in RGB888

Comment: I don't understand the question. You have a C file (the one in drive), and you are converting it to RGB888 and then you want it to be the same "representation" as what you started with. Are you asking how to generate a C file with the data in it you're generating?

Comment: It would make far more sense to use `%06X` rather than `%d` for RGB888 values, or three separate decimal byte values

Comment: @PaulHankin it's simple I have a "GIMP C-Source image dump in RGB565" I need a "GIMP C-Source image dump in RGB888"

Comment: You have misunderstood https://forum.arduino.cc/t/help-converting-rgb565-to-rgb888/275681 and replicated both fragments.  It is badly explained (a good reason to ignore it), but the second fragment does everything the first does but with a transform to 8-bit r, g and b values.  In your code you initialise r,g and b then ignore those values to immediately reassign them.  It is not at all clear what you mean by representation and encoding, or what you expect as output.

Comment: @Clifford yes I got that and I told you the 3 three lines can be removed,  don't pay attention to that. Look at the answer from mmixLinus, that's what I need , but I'm getting an error using his code, it seems the generated string is too long

Comment: @navy1978 : not in the question you haven't.  You should edit the question.  Comments don't count for much other than as a means of improving questions and answers.  Relevant information needs to be in the question, not hidden in comments.  This is not a discussion forum.  It is not clear if it is the numbers being produced that you think are incorrect (that is how your question reads) or if it is the code generation you are having trouble with,  which is suggested only in subsequent comments).  Your code makes no attempt at generating C code.  You need to clarify the question in the question.

Comment: The generated C code uses octal representation in single bytes.  Rather than generating a single 32 bit value, you should write the r, g, b values separately as octal or hex character constants.  It does not really matter if you use a string with escaped byte codes or comma separated values in hex, decimal or octal.  It is generated C code, and there are multiple ways of initialising `pixel_data` that are semantically identical.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to do to create a C file similar to the original.

1. Increase the size of the pixel buffer, because you are creating *three bytes* per pixel from the original's *two bytes.*
2. Write strings that represent the new pixel data

The first part means simply changing the `2` to `3`, so you get:

```
    guint8     pixel_data[304 * 98 * 3 + 1];
} example= {
    304, 98, 3,
```

In the second part the simplest method would be to print ALL characters in hexadecimal or octal representation. (The original code has the "printable" characters visible, but the non-printable as octal escape sequences.)

To print ALL the characters in hexadecimal representation, do similar to

```
for (i = 0; i < w * h; i++)
{
    ...
    R, G and B calculation goes here
    ...

    // Print start of line and string (every 16 pixels)
    if (i % 16 == 0)
        printf("\n\"");

    printf("\\x%02x\\x%02x\\x%02x", r, g, b);

    // Print end of string and line (every 16 pixels)
    if ((i+1) % 16 == 0)
        printf("\"\n");
}
printf("\"\n");  // Termination of last line
```

This prints three bytes in hex representation `\xab\xcd\xef` and after 16 pixels, prints end of string and newline.

Note that the byte order might need changing depending on your implementation. So `b, g, r` instead of `r, g, b`.

Comment: Thanks you, but using this code and copy-pasting the result in a file as the original one I get an error, it seems the generated string is too long:

error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive]

:(

Comment: The string within quotes needs to be exactly 304 * 98 * 3 chars long. Please check that it is. For example that w=304, h=98, and that you are printing exactly 3 chars for each pixel.